# coreplote realtime plot can't execute normally in 20ms refresh time interval

Tags: real-time, core-plot

I want to reach the goal that the XYplot can refresh every 20ms, and every refresh time add 5 new points, and show 5000 points in a graphview(xRanage = 5000, yRange = 2048).

In first 1000 points, the refresh speed look like normally, but after 1000 points, the refresh speed getting slower by every refresh event.

Although I use `inertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords` to update the data can decrease procedure to run the `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex` function, but I feel it still refresh all the graphview, not drawing point by point.

So,it still refresh slowly when after 1000 points, and getting lower by every input data.

Is it that mean coreplot doesn't suitable to do fast realtime event?

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)Refresh:(UIButton *)sender {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self
selector:@selector(show) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)show {
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random()%801+1000]];
        [dataArray2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random()%601+300]];
    }

    //[graph reloadData];
    [plotLine insertDataAtIndex:[dataArray count]-5 numberOfRecords:5];
    [plotLine2 insertDataAtIndex:[dataArray2 count]-5 numberOfRecords:5];
}

- (NSUInteger) numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {
    NSNumber *num;

    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY) {
        if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"line1"])
            num = [dataArray objectAtIndex:idx];
        else if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"line2"])
            num = [dataArray2 objectAtIndex:idx];
    }else{
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idx];
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What device are you using to display this graph? Mac or iOS? Even a Retina MacBook Pro has less than 3,000 pixels across the screen so the first thing you can do is to reduce the number of points being plotted. You also have two separate plots which makes everything take twice as long.

The display formatting of the plot (line style, area fill, plot symbols, etc.) also makes a big difference. Simplify and eliminate elements that you don't need (set the corresponding properties to `nil`). Experiment with different settings and measure the results.

Set `alignsPointsToPixels` to `NO` to save some time spent aligning each plot point with the pixel grid. For a live display of rapidly changing data, nobody will notice.

Comment: thanks your reply.

My device is iPhone5.
I also try the 'xRange = 2000' too, but the result is equal.
And the lineStyle is simplest type, just "line".

So,even have just one point is the new one, the coreplot must redraw all the data before, can't just draw a one line or one point. Am I right?

PS. I want to use coreplot to display the vital signal(ECG,Blood pressure etc.), the sample rate about 250 point/s, and I want to show 2 signal over 10s in a single graphview. So, I need to fast realtime plot.

Comment: My point is that on an iPhone 5 in landscape you only have 1,136 pixels edge-to-edge. There's not much point in trying to plot a time series that has 2,500 data points in that space. You can save the Core Plot graph a lot of work by pre-filtering your data to combine or remove points that would overlap on screen, reducing the total number of points to plot.

Comment: Thanks. I try to resize my graphview that 'yRange = 600' and 'xRang = 640', and input 1 random data at 20ms time-interval for each signal line(there have 2 signal). But the problem still exist(about 300 point later). BTW, could you tell me the drawing principle on coreplot ? Is same like I say above(So,even have just one point is the new one, the coreplot must redraw all the data before, can't just draw a one line or one point)? I want to know that my thought is right or not. Thanks.